# Can't convert SQL to django query (having doesn't work)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    stock_id, consignment_id, SUM(qty), SUM(cost) 
FROM
    warehouse_regсonsignmentproduct
WHERE
    product_id = '1'
GROUP BY  
    stock_id, consignment_id
HAVING
    SUM(qty) > 0
```

I used django ORM to create this query:

```
regСonsignmentProduct.objects
    .filter(product='1')
    .order_by('period')
    .values('stock', 'consignment')
    .annotate(total_qty=Sum('qty'), total_cost=Sum('cost'))
    .filter(total_qty__gt=0)
```

But my django query returns an incorrect result.

I think, the problem is in "annotate"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to order by the values to force grouping, so:

```
regСonsignmentProduct.objects.filter(product='1').values(
    'stock', 'consignment'
).annotate(
    total_qty=Sum('qty'),
    total_cost=Sum('cost')
).order_by('stock', 'consignment').filter(total_qty__gt=0)
```